# To craft a Javelin of Lightning, you need to be able to cast Lightning Bolt; can I use a Wand of Lightning Bolt to meet this requirement?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items, crafting

So to craft a *javelin of lightning*, you need to be able to cast *lightning bolt*. My druid can't do this, but if he bought a *wand of lightning bolt*, could he use this to meet the requirements?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! This is a pretty good first question. Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On [Magic Item Creation](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-item-creation/) says

> Note that all items have prerequisites in their descriptions. These prerequisites must be met for the item to be created. Most of the time, they take the form of spells that must be known by the item’s creator (although access through **another magic item** or spellcaster is allowed).

Thus a creator that wants to create a [*javelin of lighting*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/javelin-of-lightning/) could meet that item's *lightning bolt* prerequisite by expending charges from a *wand of lightning bolt* instead of, for example, by expending *lightning bolt* spells from his daily allotment of spells.

(Because of a *javelin of lightning*'s market price of between 1,001 and 2,000 gp, each *javelin* typically takes 2 days to create and requires a *lightning bolt* spell each day of its creation. This makes it *expensive* to meet a *javelin of lighting*'s prerequisites using a *wand of lightning bolt*—each charge of a typical wand of that 3rd-level spell at caster level 5 has a market price of 225 gp! Also, a typical druid doesn't have the spell [*lightning bolt*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/lightning-bolt) on his spell list so the typical druid will need to make Use Magic Device skill checks—or have some other way—to activate that *wand of lightning bolt*.)

Meeting this *lightning bolt* prerequisite for a magic weapon, though, is often considered unnecessary. See, on Magic Item Creation also says

> At the end of this process, the spellcaster must make a single skill check (usually Spellcraft, but sometimes another skill) to finish the item. If an item type has multiple possible skills, you choose which skill to make the check with. The DC to create a magic item is 5 + the caster level for the item.

Because the typical minimum caster level for a *lightning bolt* spell is 5, that's only a base DC 10 Spellcraft skill check, but this Spellcraft "DC to create a magic item increases by 5 for each prerequisite the caster does not meet."

So to create a *javelin of lightning* at caster level 5 *without* needing to use a charge from a *wand of lightning bolt* (or finding a dude to cast *lightning bolt* while you and he slave for a couple of days over this *javelin of lightning* or whatever) changes that Spellcraft skill check DC from 10 to only DC 15. Since a lot of folks who make magic items—wisely!—also ramp up their Spellcraft skills, *not* being able to meet directly a magic item's prerequisite or two is often considered a trivial impediment.

---

***Note:*** The item creation feat prerequisite can't be bypassed by increasing the Spellcraft skill check DC. Further, spell prerequisites can't typically be bypassed when creating potions, spell completion magic items like scrolls, or spell trigger magic items like wands. For instance, a druid couldn't increase the Spellcraft DC to bypass the lightning bolt *prerequisite of a* wand of lightning bolt *to create that item!*

Answer (score 3):

1. You [can](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-item-creation/) create a Javelin of Lightning without knowing Lightning Bolt but increases the DC by 5.
2. Having a Wand of Lightning Bolt won't help you because, although you can use an item to give you access to a spell you don't know, Lighting Bolt is not a Druid spell so a Druid can't use a Wand of Lightning Bolt.
3. If you know someone who can use a Wand of Lightning Bolt like a wizard or sorcerer then you can [cooperatively](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-item-creation/) make the Javelin of Lighting.

Comment: I'm unsure why this was downvoted... this is accurate.

Comment: Accuracy does not mean good answer. The information is correct, but it repeats something the OP already knows and is presented terribly.

Comment: "Lighting Bolt is not a Druid spell so a Druid can't use a Wand of Lightning Bolt.", This is incorrect, a druid can use a wand of lightning bolt, they just need to make a DC20 use magic device check to do so.

Comment: @williamporter I think it's fair for answers not to use *typical*, *usual*, and *normal* and just assume a regular ol' druid unless the asker provides more information, but I may be in the minority. Further, while an answer can use words like *typical et al.* to make it clear that exceptions may exist, actually *listing* every exception in an exception-based game that's as vast and cumbersome as *Pathfinder* places an undue burden on the answer. (Every answer would be a book were it to list every exception!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan, if it were some corner case that a druid cannot use a wand except in a specific case, I would agree. Except, there is an entire skill specifically for the purpose of using magic items and you can use it while untrained. The information is just incorrect in this case, a Druid can *typically* use any wand, they may just need to make a check.

Comment: @williamporter Nonetheless, the skill Use Magic Device can't be used untrained, and the skill Use Magic Device isn't on the typical druid's skill list. I can totally understand *wanting* the phrase *Lighting Bolt is not a Druid spell so a Druid can't use a Wand of Lightning Bolt* to say instead *Lighting Bolt is not a Druid spell so a **typical** Druid can't use a Wand of Lightning Bolt*, though, but, like I said, I don't think it's necessary, even if my answers tend to include such language. As the question is posed generally, that phrase is, as it stands, is accurate generally.